# textbox required equal false

Tags: c#, javascript

how do I make the textbox that required equal to false in this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= chkSpecialIntegration.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
               $("#<%= ddlTypeSpecialIntegration.ClientID %>").show();

                document.getElementById('<%=txtTotalScoreDebit.ClientID %>').Required = false; }
else{
 $("#<%= ddlTypeSpecialIntegration.ClientID %>").hide();
 document.getElementById('<%=txtTotalScoreDebit.ClientID %>').Required = true;
}

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `.required`, lower-case, and you can simplify your code further as well since you're dealing with booleans, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#<%= chkSpecialIntegration.ClientID %>").click(function () {
    $("#<%= ddlTypeSpecialIntegration.ClientID %>").toggle(this.checked);
    document.getElementById('<%=txtTotalScoreDebit.ClientID %>').required = !this.checked;
  });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/FnPNv/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required)?

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: "required"
  }
});
```

Comment: There's a DOM attribute `required` in HTML5 :)

Comment: yes but i need one method for is required="false" in javascript

Comment: @Nick Craver: I see. I should start reading something about HTML5 then :)